# Build realtime event driven applications with WebSocket and fallback technologies

Tags: ssl, proxy, websocket, long-polling

I need to build a `server` and a `client` that can exchange data in real time with a company's proxy between them. No one has the authorisation to amend the proxy's configuration (in order to allow the `WebSocket` protocol).

I would need a fallback technology such as `long-polling`.

Example: client is a user's PC employee. He needs to exchange data with the server, located in the cloud and separated by company's proxy.

Ideally, I would use `WebSocket` with `SSL`, but I know some proxies are not configured for `WebSocket` messages and thus could reject the connection.

The app would therefore switch to another `push` technology such as `long-polling`, increasing the chances of getting a successful connection (is 100% guaranteed with proxies? Giving that there are several types of proxies...)

Are there any libraries/frameworks proposing such features?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, [secure WebSocket connections do fine through proxies](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers).

- In .NET you have [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)
- In node.js you have [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: I've seen the post you've linked. However, "usually" is not enough in a business environment, as we cannot allow ourselves to say to the client that our solution is going to work if it may end up failing at the proxy entrance.
I would need something that mixes WebSocket + long-polling technology as a fallback.

EDIT: It's true that socket.io handles fallback. If I don't have other choice I'll go with it.